# What were the sources of Jewish immigration to Israel between 1939-1951?

Tags: israel, immigration

Which countries did Israeli Jews emigrate from in 1939-1951 ? [This table](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Immigration/immigration_by_country2.html) is incomplete (for example, it only shows the origin of ~3000 in 1948). Is better data available (preferably online) ?

Comment: Wow, that's a really, really strange table. As you say, it only accounts for 30% of the total for 1948 as reported *in that table's summary column* itself, and totally fails to mention any part of Europe except for the UK and the Soviet Union, nor any Middle-Eastern or North-African countries (where a large part came from). Furthermore, the citation link at the bottom is to the home page of the IBS, not to a specific report.

Comment: I don't have the resources to provide a full answer right now, but the Wikipedia page on [Aliyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliyah) can provide more thorough numbers, and much more extensively sourced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it used to divide the immigration to Israel into "waves"(free translation from Hebrew).
during this year, 1939 to 1951, it used to include three waves:

1. [Aliya Bet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliyah_Bet)(free translation: Immigration 2nd) during WW2
   Included ~17,000 immigrants, most of them Europeans.
2. Aliya Bet after WW2
   Included ~85,000 immigrants, most of them Europeans
3. The mass "Aliya" since Israeli independence(May '48) to 1951
   Included ~650,000 immigrants from many countries; as Iraq(20%),Romania(19%), Poland(17%), Yemen(8%), Morocco(7%), Bulgaria(6%), Turkey(%), Libya(5%) and Iran, Czechoslovakia, Hungary, Germany, Egypt, USSR, Yugoslavia(all of them 3% or less). [Reference for these data can be found here(In Hebrew)](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA#/media/File:AliahHamonit.JPG)